# Move from Observable to BehaviorSubject

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8, angular-observable

I have and observable and a condition on it:

```
let data$: Observable<DataModel[]>;

this.httpClient.get<DataModel[]>>(`data`)
   .pipe(map((result: DataModel[]>) => this.data$ = result));

let result: boolean = this.data$.pipe(
  map(x => x.find(y => y.child.some(z => z.id == id))),
  map(x => x ? ['B'].some(y => y === x.child.find(z => z.id == 2)) : false));
```

I now changed `data$` from `Observable<DataModel[]>` to `BehaviorSubject<DataModel[]>` and used `this.data$.next(result)` to set `data$` value.

```
let data$: BehaviorSubject<DataModel[]>;

this.httpClient.get<DataModel[]>>(`data`)
   .pipe(map((result: DataModel[]>) => this.data$.next(result));

let result: boolean = this.data$.pipe(
  map(x => x.find(y => y.child.some(z => z.id == id))),
  map(x => x ? ['B'].some(y => y === x.child.find(z => z.id == 2)) : false));
```

When using the BehaviorSubject I get the error on `this.data$.pipe(`

```
 undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.data$.pipe')
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize your `BehaviorSubject`

```
let data$ = new BehaviorSubject<DataModel[]>(INITIAL_VALUE or undefined);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the constructor part.

```
let data$: BehaviorSubject<DataModel[]> = new BehaviorSubject<DataModel[]>([]);
```

Have a look at: [Component interaction on angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

The only difference from an behaviorsubject and subject is that a behaviorsubject takes an initial values and holds a reference to the latest value so you could subscribe to it and always get a value. Subject on the other hand is all about timing.